# Git I have an error when merge the file

Tags: git

In Git while merging the python files error will occurs.Please share your ideas. How to remove all pyc files and merge the content. This error occurs when it pull the updation from repository. Those pyc file gets updated frequently. when I pull updation from repository those error occurs everytime

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    addressbook/views.pyc
    allauth/account/admin.pyc
    allauth/account/auth_backends.pyc
    allauth/account/context_processors.pyc
    allauth/account/forms.pyc
    allauth/account/management/__init__.pyc
    allauth/account/urls.pyc
    allauth/account/views.pyc
    allauth/exceptions.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/adapter.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/admin.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/app_settings.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/context_processors.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/forms.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/helpers.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/base.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/forms.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/locale.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/linkedin/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/linkedin/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/linkedin/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/__init__.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/client.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/__init__.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/client.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/twitter/provider.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/twitter/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/providers/twitter/views.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/signals.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/urls.pyc
    allauth/socialaccount/views.pyc
    allauth/urls.pyc
    crispy_forms/base.pyc
    crispy_forms/bootstrap.pyc
    crispy_forms/exceptions.pyc
    crispy_forms/helper.pyc
    crispy_forms/layout.pyc
    crispy_forms/layout_slice.pyc
    crispy_forms/utils.pyc
    feeds/views.pyc
    lettertemplate/forms.pyc
    lettertemplate/views.pyc
    quorum/forms.pyc
    quorum/views.pyc
    registration/admin.pyc
    registration/forms.pyc
    registration/models.pyc
    registration/urls.pyc
    registration/views.pyc
    rosetta/polib.pyc
    rosetta/poutil.pyc
    rosetta/signals.pyc
    rosetta/storage.pyc
    rosetta/urls.pyc
    rosetta/views.pyc
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: add ``*.py[cod]`` to your ``.gitignore`` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.pyc` files probably should not be tracked since, as you're seeing, they will change constantly.  Typically build products are not stored in git for just this reason.  If you have the option I would untrack them in the upstream repository.

If that's not an option your only choice is to move or delete your local `.pyc` files.  You can do this with the following command (note: this assumes you want to delete *all* `.pyc` file at or below the current directory.

```
 find . -iname '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;
```

After doing this you should be able to do the merge since there will be no local files to overwrite.

Answer (score 6):

This error is occurring because you're tracking `.pyc` files in your repository (which you shouldn't do). It was probably the result of a `git add .` What you should do is delete all the `.pyc` files with `git rm`, then merge again. Git won't complain, as it won't be copying repository `.pyc` files over the local versions.

As Nick suggested, adding `.pyc` and other files that don't make sense to track to a global (or repository-level) `.gitignore` is probably a good idea. If you do so, `git add .` won't automatically add these files. Check out [GitHub's official list of suggested `.gitignore` files](https://github.com/github/gitignore).

Comment: user should also add *.pyc in .gitignore.

Comment: Yup. You beat me to my second edit - wanted to elaborate on the problem. =)

Answer (score 3):

To remove these files from the index use:

`find . -name *.pyc | xargs rm`

Then you can ignore compiled python files with the following statement in you `.gitgnore`

```
*.py[cod]
```

Once you have told git to ignore these files, you will no longer get the warning message.

I prefer to ignore compiled files in my "global" gitignore file (more about that [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#global-gitignore)), but you can do this on a per repository basis as well.

Comment: This is something the user should do, but it won't fix the current problem.